# Is it possible to filter the open file dialog that is invoked from a html input file field by a specific filename?

Tags: html, html-input

Because my users have to select a file from a folder with a lot of files in it, I would like to add a filter to the open file dialog that is invoked from an input file field. I understand that `<input type="file">` field allows filtering by file extensions like this:

```
<input accept=".txt" type="file" />
```

But, is it possible to set a filter to a specific filename, too?

In a C# winform app I would just set the `Filter` property of a `openFileDialog` to `Foo|bar.txt` and it would only show me `bar.txt` files.

Comment: you would either need to add your own client or server side validation (or both), but yes it is possible

Comment: I don't think it is secure to specify file upload parameters in the frontend. I would recommend you to check this in the backend (e.g. PHP). This might become a serious security issue.

Comment: Anyone can create a filename that will match the validation - It could be the file you're expecting or a fake file that the client submitted. So I don't think you should bother yourself too much with this type of validation

Comment: @Maurice Its just thought as a convenient option for the user that has to select a specific file from a folder that has A LOT of files with the same extension in it and he only needs to select the one with a specific name. The backend already handles it when the wrong file is uploaded.

Comment: It's not possible to restrict the selection of a file in the (windows) explorer. You could show a message or something if the file is not matching the one you want. Use javascript for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any attribute for it in HTML but you can do it by using javascript.

I have created a basic example. Here I am accepting only the filename say `specific-filename`. You can set it according to your needs.

```js
let file = document.getElementById('file');
file.addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
  const fullPath = e.target.value;
  const filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').split('.')[0];
  console.log(filename); //the name of your file
  if(filename!=='specific-filename') {
    e.target.value='';  // this resets the value of input field
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" id="file">
</div>
```

If you have a form, you can do it similarly at the time of form submission and not allowing the submission unless filename matched. Here, I have intercepted the process `onchange` of input field

Hope it helps!

Comment: My question was abviously not precisely enough expressing what I wanted to achieve. I tried to rephrase it properly. Sorry for your effort, but thanks.